# Hashtable comparator problem

Tags: java, hashtable, comparator

Hi guys i've never written a comparator b4 and im having a real problem. I've created a hashtable.

```
Hashtable <String, Objects> ht;
```

Could someone show how you'd write a comparator for a Hashtable? the examples i've seen overide equals and everything but i simply dont have a clue. The code below is not mine but an example i found, the key thing in hashtables means i cant do it like this i guess.

```
 public class Comparator implements Comparable<Name> {
        private final String firstName, lastName;

        public void Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
            if (firstName == null || lastName == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
        this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String firstName() { return firstName; }
        public String lastName()  { return lastName;  }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Name))
                return false;
            Name n = (Name)o;
            return n.firstName.equals(firstName) &&
                   n.lastName.equals(lastName);
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return 31*firstName.hashCode() + lastName.hashCode();
        }

        public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
        }

        public int compareTo(Name n) {
            int lastCmp = lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);
            return (lastCmp != 0 ? lastCmp :
                    firstName.compareTo(n.firstName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to compare two `Hashtable` instances, or two items contained within the hashtable?

Comment: That's about 100 times longer than any comparator I've ever written. Why do you need a comparator at all? What makes you think you do? What do your keys look like?

Comment: Have you actually implemented your custom hashtable, or are you using `java.util.Hashtable` with a typo in your code (`HashTable`)?

Comment: Yeah sorry so used  to camelcase im using Hashtable. Im just comparing elements of a collection alphabetically

Comment: *What is it exactly you're trying to do, that is, what are you hoping this will now allow you to do?* Answer that and we'll be able to help you!

Comment: For those who may be wondering, I fixed the typo mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparators are used to sort a list. A `Hashtable` (note the case) is not ordered by its elements. You can order a table by iterating over its keys (in the case you'd want to order on its keys, I presume) and put them in a `List`. The next thing to do is to sort the `List` and iterate over the `List`, and use a `get` out of the `Hashtable` to get its associated value.

Here is an example (using `HashMap`, since it's more integrated with the rest of the Java Collections. A `HashMap` is essentially the same as `Hashtable`.):

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    HashMap<String, Object> x = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    x.put("second", " ordered!");
    x.put("first", "Correctly");

    LinkedList<String> keys = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(final String f : x.keySet()) {
        keys.add(f);
    }
    Collections.sort(keys, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String first, String second) {
            // return -1 is "first <  second"
            // return 1  is "first >  second"
            // return 0  is "first == second"
            return first.compareTo(second);
        }
    });

    for(final String f : keys) {
        System.out.print(x.get(f));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The order of the list `keys` is sorted by the anonymous `Comparator` class. It will sort alphabetically, as is the default for Strings. You can use your own key object, like you mentioned. If you don't implement `Comparator` in this key object, then you can supply, as in the above example. Else you can use the default `Comparator` by calling:

```
Collections.sort(keys);
```

Which will use the classes implementation of `Comparator`. If it does not implement `Comparator`, then it will throw an exception (since it will cast to a `Comparator`)

Comment: Hi, thats fantastic, so you're saying to use Hashmap instead of Hashtable. I dont understand why you are using a linked list though?

Comment: Because neither `HashMap` (note the case of the M) nor `Hashtable` (small t), are "ordered". Thus their elements are in a semi-random order stored, to enhance performance. I use a `LinkedList` because I use a lot of `.add(f);`, and `LinkedList` is optimized for append/removal. Then the `List` is ordered using `Collections.sort`. A list has internal representation of order, it is "ordered", and thus the order of the keys of the `HashMap` is stored in the `List`. Iterating over the `List` will give the keys in correct order.

Comment: A Map (HashMap) does not do ordering of its elements.  The order of the keys is determined by the hash value of the key object, so you can't sort a HashMap (or Hashtable).  The point of the LinkedList is to order the keys of your HashMap alphabetically, you can then use this ordered list to get at the associated values.  Are you sure a Hashtable is really what you want to be using?

Comment: If you want to order by the keys, why not use a TreeMap?

Map sortedMap = new TreeMap(comparatorInstance);
sortedMap.putAll(hashMap);

Or better yet, use a tree map from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A Comparator will tell you which of two items is larger. If this has meaning for your HashTable, only you can say what the meaning is. It would be very unusual to want to compare two HashTables in this way.

Comment: So you're saying i shouldnt have done a hash table? would something like a treeset be more suitable? basically i have a collection of data (currently in a hash table) that i want to arrange alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Comparator class. That's a Name class that implements Comparable.

Hashtable and Hashmap don't use either Comparator or Comparable. If you want sorted keys use a TreeMap.